# Web Audio API microphone EQ

Tags: web-audio-api, javascript-audio-api

Does anyone know if it is possible to add EQ / effects filtering to the live microphone input within a html5 enabled web page?

To be clear I'm not talking about adjusting the sound of a pre-recorded wav/mp3 playing in the HTMl5 player, there are plenty of those,  I am talking about adjusting the microphone characteristics in live time while the stream is being captured from the chosen mic source.

Has anyone managed to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Here is one (not great) example: https://mdn.github.io/voice-change-o-matic

Comment: Thank you kindly for this, it gives me a start to work with